# between date and greater than date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the data set and sysdate - 3rd Oct

```
ITEM    Date_from   Date_to
1234    1/1/2018    9/1/2018
1234    1/1/2018    10/1/2018
1234    1/1/2018    10/4/2018
1234    1/1/2019    12/31/2019
```

MY query:

```
select * from test_date where effect_to >= sysdate 
  minus
  select * from test_date where effect_to < sysdate ;
```

Correct Result:

```
1234    1/1/2018    10/4/2018
1234    1/1/2019    12/31/2019
```

Any better query ?

need to item dates which are currently effective and also effective for future dates.

Comment: no need to subtract (minus) that which you have already filtered with the first where clause

Comment: I think you want to return rows where the sysdate is between `date_from` and `date_to`, but in your example query, they're both `effect_to`... is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want:

```
where effect_to > sysdate
```

or perhaps:

```
where effect_to >= trunc(sysdate)
```

depending on whether the last date is inclusive or exclusive.